# Pick lines with highest values from np.zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following data structure:

```
Pl = np.zeros((7,2,7))
Pl[0,0,1]=1
Pl[1,0,2]=1
Pl[2,0,3]=1
Pl[5,0,6]=0.9
Pl[5,0,5]=0.1
...
Pl[5,1,4]=1
```

How can I get the entry with a specified first value and that has the highest assigned value?

For example for x=5, I want to get Pl[5,1,4]. I have seen max but I can't specify the value of x.

Thank you!

Comment: `Pl[x].max()`.?

Comment: Thank you @coldspeed, I think that returns the max value (1) but I want to return the array [5,1,4]. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want the maximum value or the 3D location of the maximum value?

Comment: @Pavan I want the 3D location of the maximum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

Pl = np.zeros((7, 2, 7))
Pl[0, 0, 1] = 1
Pl[1, 0, 2] = 1
Pl[2, 0, 3] = 1
Pl[5, 0, 6] = 0.9
Pl[5, 0, 5] = 0.1
Pl[5, 1, 4] = 1

res = np.array([5, *np.unravel_index(Pl[5].argmax(), Pl[5].shape)])
# array([5, 1, 4])
```

Here, `Pl[5].argmax()` gets the maximal value. It will be a 1D integer index, but you can convert it to a 2D index of Pl[5] with `np.unravel_index`. Finally, we are missing the index along the zeroeth dimension that we know is  `5`. Just prepend it and return the array.